# How to display data form url parameter in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, routes

Creating app in ionic where i have to pass parameter form one page to another page and display the data form that parameter , data comes form json . My problem is how to get data from that parameter . Is  i use ui-router or any thing kindly check my code tell me how to do it because when i using ui-router thats give error.

Controller

```
.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope,$http) {


     $http.get("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
      $scope.offerName = ''; //set initially
      $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
      $scope.filteredOffers = [];



  });
 $scope.showData = function(offer_name, index) {
        $scope.offerName = offer_name;
      $scope.filteredOffers = $scope.myData.filter(function(offer) {
        return offer.offer_name == $scope.offerName;
      });
        $scope.selectedIndex = index;

      }


})
```

Datapage which send the data parameter

```
 <div class="item col-sm-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 " ng-repeat="da in myData | unique: 'store_image'" >
            <div class="thumbnail " >

                   <img class="thumbnail  img-responsive " ng-src="{{ da.store_image}}" 
ng-click="showData(da.offer_name, $index)"
                    />   
                <div class="caption">
                   <a class="item item-text-wrap" ng-href="#/Deals/{{da.offer_name }}" ng-click="showData(da.offer_name, $index)"
 >
                    <b class="group inner list-group-item-heading center-block">
                        {{da.offer_name | limitTo: 12 }} Deals </b>

              </a>

                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Page which i want to display the  data as per parameter ..

```
 <div ng-repeat="offer in filteredOffers">
      <div class="couponCode">{{offer.coupon_code}}</div>
      <div class="couponTitle">{{offer.coupon_title}}</div>
      <div class="couponDescription">{{offer.coupon_Description}}</div>
    </div>
```

Kindly suggest me ..
Thanks in advance

Here the dealctrl which try to fatch data

```
.controller("dealsCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $stateParams)
 { 
    $http({ 
        url: "tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8",
         method: "get", 

    params: { offer_name: $stateParams.offer_name } })

    .then(function (response) 
    { $scope.da = response.data;
            console.log($scope.da);

     })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Url parameters should be used to identify a resource, not to pass objects. In order to achieve this there is a better method: use a `Service` or a `Factory` to store data you wants and access them between controllers. Here a simple example:

```
app.controller('firstController', function(MyService) {

    var data = getSomeData();

    MyService.dataToStore = data;
)}


app.factory('MyService', function() {

    return {

         dataToStore: {}
    }
})

app.controller('secondController', function(MyService) {

    var data = MyService.dataToStore;
})
```

If you are using Ionic you can listen for events like "beforeEnter" in order to get data when you enter a view.